# How to fix " error: cannot find symbol class RecyclerAdapter "

Tags: android, android-studio

```
    if (apps.size() > 1) {
            mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(apps);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

     recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new SlideInLeftAnimator());
//                RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
//                recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new SlideInUpAnimator(new OvershootInterpolator(1f)));

                    recyclerView.getItemAnimator().setAddDuration(10000);

                    mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(apps);
                    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new SlideInUpAnimator(new OvershootInterpolator(1f)));
                    recyclerView.computeHorizontalScrollExtent();
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    getAllICONS();
```

I'm editing the code of an Android app and facing the problem with 4 errors and all these 4 errors are same, Following is the error messages 
error: cannot find symbol class RecyclerAdapter

please check and guide to get rid of this issue.
Thank you

Tried to clean the code and rebuilding but it's not solving the issue

Comment: Can you please describe your problem in brief and put some code?

Comment: Can you please share a piece of code and logcat data for more clarification?

Comment: @sagarchavda code shared, Please check it now.
and there is nothing in logcat. logcat area is empty.

Comment: Bro, android was not able to find this class that you have used "RecyclerAdapter".
Can you post this class?